# Google Places API does not returns photos via photoreference in android

Tags: android, google-places-api, http-status-code-500

I am using Google places API to get the details of particular restaurant. 
Now, I wish to display the image of the restaurant in my android app . 
For that, I referred [this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) . 
However, the  below link which is required to get an error gives me a 500 error and when I use `http://` in the link instead of `https://` , it gives an image which says you have exceeded the API limit.

I am using Gl[enter link description here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)ide to display these images. I dont think there's any issue with the Glide . The url generated does not gives any output.

Below is the code :

```
    String url = mPlaces.getIcon();
    String photoreference = mPlaces.getPhotoreference();
    String restaurantpic = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?" +
            "maxwidth=400" +
            "&photoreference=" +photoreference +
            "&key="+API_KEY;

Log.d("Loading restaurantpic" , restaurantpic);

    Glide
            .with(mContext)
            .load(restaurantpic)
            .centerCrop()
           // .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
            //.crossFade()
            .into(mImageViewIcon);
```

This is an [example](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRwAAAAGLLaAGNuc_FNAe4VpENHMoKPUG3hyvyDN8OUQZVrwszDVamgh5oGKSJAey72OamNWl6EiWeB40m_t1kj23-bj37JGUsH0wKKZBJDDVHExVliBO0G8SSKMioX3hrNHhDj4PcyyBkcGlsqpDFEu7ocuhIQlqJ3MxcXxyYwivNIFwZb0RoUnCXEd_fL4N6YsSVdp08ABGN-Nek&key=%3CA_VALID_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY%3E) of restaurantpic URL with https protocol which gives 500 error. The same with HTTP protocol gives below attached [image]image(Which is for quota filled).

Comment: Have you checked the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) to see if you actually are exceeding your quota?  It seems likely if you're getting the quota error image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So guys, It was my silly mistake to use "referenece" field from the JSON data instead of "photo-reference" field .

The issue was resolved .

Comment: This helped me a lot.i had the same issue just about 10 minutes ago

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is having some trouble with this:

If you are trying to use the Web Service API key on Android it will not work correctly if you are also trying to restrict that API key to only certain Android Apps (by package name/fingerprint)

See here:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key#get_an_api_key
**Note: The Google Places API Web Service does not work with an Android or iOS restricted API key.**